# Can’t login after resetting the password in my Asp.Net Core web API application

Tags: asp.net, ef-code-first, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using EF core with Identity in my Asp.Net core web API application. On resetting the password identity changes the password in to DB but it doesn’t allow me to login with the new password.
After restarting the web API application, it works fine with the new password.
Please can anyone help me?

Code in my Configure Services

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<XYZDbContext>((options)=>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<XYZDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
   }
```

Code in Entities

```
   namespace XYZ.Entities
      {
          public class XYZDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
          {

                public XYZDbContext(DbContextOptions<XYZDbContext> options):base(options)

                 {
                 }

           }
       }
```

Comment: You are starting the application and providing user and password which are used to access the database by the application. Later on you are changing that password - I'm I right? That isn't not a common case - you shouldn't be doing that. Simply update config (with user and password) file and restart application.

Comment: No. I am not changing password for database user.  I am changing password for Application user I just created using Identity framework. 
If the user resets or changes his password, he can't sign-in with the new credentials until the ASP.NET App is restarted. Looks like there is some caching issue with EF Core.

Comment: here is my startup.cs [link](https://github.com/rsoni20/Startup)